# MongoDb - Return bulks of N elements from the end of a nested array looping backwards at each call (pagination)

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a collection of categories, and each category has its array of `_id` from a different collection.
My goal is to create an infinite scrolling by giving N records every time but from the end (the last record is always the most recent).

Category

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("625167ce3859b8465ccf69dc"), 
    "name" : {
        "en" : "Category #1"
    }, 
    "tracks" : [
        ObjectId("627f8475c229513838eed070"), 
        ObjectId("627f84b4c229513838eed074"), 
        ObjectId("6280ef548b97521c1f462266"), 
        ObjectId("6280ef68d147e83534f4ca03"), 
        ObjectId("6280ef6ad147e83534f4ca07"), 
        ObjectId("6280ef6bd147e83534f4ca0b"),
        // and so on..
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
categories
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: ObjectId(categoryId),
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          tracks: {
            $slice: ["$tracks", -N],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "tracks",
          as: "tracks",
          localField: "tracks",
          foreignField: "_id",
          pipeline: [{ $sort: { uploadedDate: -1 } }],
        },
      },
    ])
```

So basically I slice the array, to get last N elements and then look them up on `tracks` collection. But I want to get N records from the end between specific range.
For example, if I have 100 records, so giving the iteration number 0, and bulk size: 25, the last 25 elements will be returned (index 75-99).
On iteration 1, the next (moving backwards) 25 elements will be returned (index 50-74), and so on...

Comment: @nimrodserok can you show an example? if I add `skip` it applies the categories, but not the tracks. Also I want it to be efficient, to do it before the lookup so it will run faster.

Comment: Actually you can use `$slice` from a position: [see this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

Comment: @nimrodserok that's what I tried but, I can't use a negative number if I add `position`. the thing is I need N records from the end (last element is always the most recent) so I need 25 records from last index - 25, and so on.. I can slice to -N but doing so will always give 25, 50, 75 last records (will have to load the same elements + new 25) rather than 25 records every time between a specific range

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If you have a list of 100 documents, you can get the last X **OR** a range (index a to index c), logically, there is no such thing, both of them...Do you want the query to give you one of these options according to its input?

Comment: @nimrodserok let's say i have 10K documents, I want to get each time 25 documents. the 10K doc is the most recent, so I need to get the documents from the end.. 10,000 to 9,975, and then 9,975 to 9,950 and so on. the thing is I need to get N elements between a specific range but from the end of the collection if there is a a way of doing so, I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can so something like:

**EDIT:** to support edge cases:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {_id: ObjectId("625167ce3859b8465ccf69dc")}
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      avilableCount: {$max: [
        {$subtract: [{$size: "$tracks" }, bulkSize * iterations]},  
      0]}
    }
  },
   {
    $project: {
      tracks: {
        $cond: [{$eq: ["$avilableCount",  0]},
          [],
          {$slice: ["$tracks", {
                $max: [
                  {$subtract: [{$size: "$tracks"}, bulkSize * (iterations + 1)]}, 0]},
              {$min: [bulkSize , "$avilableCount"]}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/irtIeJDOylS)

This will return you a bulk of tracks with size `bulkSize`, starting from the end of the list for the first iteration and going backwards along the iterations. So if you have 100 tracks with index 0-99 and the `bulkSize` is 25, you will get tracks 75-99 for the first iteration, 50-74 for the 2nd iteration 25-49 for the 3rd...
The `avilableCount` allows us to look at the edge cases:
In the edge case where only a part of the bulk size is available it will return this part, and if non is available it will return [].

Comment: It's kind of what I wanted, but in case I have 85 pages, bulkSize is 25 and iteration is 3, it should return 0-9 indexes, instead its returning 71-85. And also is there any way to use conditions? if bulkSize * (iterations + 1) > tracks.length so not to return elements by default? (I need to know when it ends so ill stop scrolling the user)

Comment: Updated the question according to the comment

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was trying to achieve, working as expected. thanks achi I appreciate!